# Drupal Version Tags in 2017 and onward?

Tags: support, tags

On [meta.Drupal.SE](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/) there is a question about "[Version Tags in 2017 and onward?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3632/39516)". It explains the guidance from the diamond moderators, as of 2017/02/25, about when it is appropriate to use tags about specific Drupal versions.

On SO, there are similar Drupal version tags, apart from the [drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal) tag itself (which, obviously, can be used for any Drupal question). More specifically: [drupal-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-8), [drupal-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-7), [drupal-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-6) and [drupal-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-5).

**My question**:

What's the guidance on SO about using the [drupal-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-8), [drupal-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-7), [drupal-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-6) and [drupal-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-5) tags? I.e. is it ***yes*** or ***no*** similar to the guidance from Drupal.SE?

Comment: No guidance. I prefer the U&L way: no version tags.